# setting value into history and grabbing it on another page react

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have this:

```
const editById = (id) => {
console.log(id);
axios
  .post(`/getDocToEdit`, { id: id })
  .then((RESPONSE) => {
    console.log(RESPONSE); // do it and if you have the response, everything 
    this.props.history.push({
          id: id // your data array of objects
      }).then(() => {
        console.log(id, " worked");
        window.location = "/admin/services/:site";
      })
   
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle the errors here
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

it is setting the `id` like within this.props.history.push. then, on my other page, I am trying to grab the id using `console.log(this.props.history.id)`, but it is not working. am I doing it the right way?

Comment: why do you use history.push AND window.location ?

Comment: I am just trying to store value and get it on other page. I am not sure how to do this, I've never used this way before, so I don't know what I can and can't use

Comment: i hope my answer helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to do it like this:

```
history.push({
   pathname: `/admin/services/${site}`,
   state: {
     id: id
   }
})
```

and then you can access the passed id with

```
const history = useHistory()
console.log(history.location.state.id)
```

on the other page.